# php running the process where it would be stop

Tags: php

I am working on a e-commerce site.

I want to read data from file (CSV or TXT). First time I read data from 1 to 1000 then the process is accidentally stopped. So second time read process should start from 1001.

Anyone please help me!

Comment: Actually it is a common concept and also I don't know which code that I will give because so many coding lines are there.

Comment: I just saved the row id or line id and at the second time reading i just skipped the lines until specific line id came.

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1*

Insert elements one by one to table like:

```
// take all data
$prods = json_decode(file_get_contents('products.php'));

while (!empty($prods)) {
    // remove first element from array. Origin array is changed
    $product = array_shift($prods);

    // do your insert logic
    $this->insert($product);

    // for some reasons you don't insert all products
    if ($this->break) {
        break;
    }
}

// write to file what is left, if any
file_put_contents('products.php', json_encode($prods));
```

*Option 2*

Sort products by ID and empty-loop while you don't reach your element:

```
 foreach ($products as $product) {
     if ($product->id < $lastId) {
         continue;
     }

     $this->insert($product);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your response but it is not working for me. Reasons are Option1==>Total no of products are above 11 lac, so if I stored then the time will be too long. Option2==>The products ids are random.